# Complex Integral meaning

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry

For me, I know how finding complex integral but my problem how can image it in complex plan I mean in realty what is complex integral? I hope someone have any idea about it and give me some resources to see it. In real numbers means the area under curve but here I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Re your last sentence: On the contrary, integrating a real-function doesn't mean calculating the area (well, of course, we may use integration to calculate areas of regions, but that's not what the integral *means.*).

So let's start with integrals of real functions. What do they mean? Well, this is just a way to assign numerical values to functions over their domains in such a way that it has properties we expect a totality to have. That is, we intuitively think of the integral as the totality or aggregate of a function over some domain. We usually have in mind properties that we want such a representative quantity to satisfy. This leads us to define the integral.

If we can do this for real-valued functions, what stops us from being able to do it with complex-valued ones, since they are more-or-less the same in behaviour? I mean, there's nothing much more radically different and we may make the extension to complex functions too. Indeed, this question really isn't about integrals, but complex values. If you agree that there are uses for complex numbers, then it should immediately become clear that there would be uses for complex-valued integrals too.

Comment: thank you for you answer, do you mean the integral of complex function is just its value through specific domain through a path etc.

Comment: @user707038 I mean that you may conceive of it as a kind of sum of the values of the function over some domain, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first example students learn is a contour integral where the contour is the circle $C:=\{\left.z\in\Bbb C\right||z-a|=r\}$ for some $a\in\Bbb C,\,r>0$, so with the parameterisation $z=a+re^{it}$ we have $$\oint_Cf(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{it})ire^{it}dt.$$(If we're seeking an intuition about complex integrals, what *else* is it going to be?) A similar interpretation is possible of more general contour integrals; you just need to parameterize  a contour $C$ in the form $z=g(t)$ with $g:\,\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb C$, viz. $$\oint_Cf(z)dz=\int_{t_\min}^{t_\max}f(g(t))g^\prime(t)dt.$$Be careful not to try writing this as $\int_{g(t_\min)}^{g(t_\max)}f(w)dw$, since $g$ may not biject. Indeed, if we applied such a fallacy to the circular contour with $g(t)=a+re^{it}$, we would conclude the result is always $0$, which admits the counterexample $f(w)=\frac{1}{w-a}$.